# Validate PartialView inside another model form MVC 5

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

[image: Form sample]

I have 2 models in this form The main model is Beverage

```
[Serializable]
    public class Beverage
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BeverageId { get; set; }
        public int BeverageTypeId { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public bool IsAvailableForGuests { get; set; }
        public bool IsTaxable { get; set; }

        public virtual BeverageType BeverageType { set; get; }

        public virtual ICollection<BeveragePrice> BeveragePrices { set; get; }
    }
```

The second model is BeveragePrice

```
[Serializable]
    public class BeveragePrice
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BeveragePriceId { set; get; }
        [ForeignKey("Beverage")]
        public int BeverageId { set; get; }
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }
        public double Taxes { get; set; }
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Beverage Beverage { set; get; }
    }
```

BeveragePrice is a PartialView has its own model

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Beverage Prices</h4>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "any", @onkeypress = "return OnlyNumeric(this);" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Taxes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Taxes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "any", @onkeypress = "return OnlyNumeric(this);" } })
            </div>
            <div class="measures">
                <span>%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 ">
                <div class="form-control custominput">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, "ClockDateTime", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-right">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input  type="button" value="Add Price" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see I have a button called addprice and another button to submit the form called create. What I want is when I click add price I validate only the price div and then I will add the price to a table under the price form because the user can add more than one price.

Comment: What do you mean "_validate the price div"_? You don't have any validation attributes on you model properties and nowhere do you render `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so there is nowhere to display errors anyway. Next you have not indicated how you are saving the `BeveragePrice` (are you using ajax?) nor how you add a new `BeveragePrice` so its impossible to give you an answer. Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689) might get you some hints. And stop using data models in your view! Use view models

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the partial view to action as BeveragePrice, so the action should look like, see the link below

[ASP.NET MVC Validation in Partial View and return to Parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633923/asp-net-mvc-validation-in-partial-view-and-return-to-parent-view)

Or
If you are familiar with jQuery,You can use jQuery to validate the price, retrieve it and show it in an table below.

Comment: I think you can only validate a form. price is just part of the form.