# Asp.NET unique item in list validaton

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have view with tasks. Each task has an @Ajax.Action link to add this task to check list.
My view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tasks) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaskText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TillDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => item.State, new { id=item.Id, @class="state"})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Add To check list", "AddToCheckList", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CheckListPartial" });
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My controller action:

```
    public PartialViewResult AddToCheckList(int id)
    {
        context.AddTaskToCheckList(id);
        return PartialView("_LoadCheckList", context.CheckList);
    }
```

And CheckList class:

```
public class CheckList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; } = new List<Models.Task>();
}
```

Now adding works, but I have a problem: I can add one task to check list several times. 
How can I validate if check list contains task and show error message?

**UPD:**
 I've make this with my controller. Validation works, but message is not shown.

```
    public PartialViewResult AddToCheckList(int id)
    {
        if(context.CheckList.Tasks.Exists(t=>t.Id==id))
            ModelState.AddModelError("CheckList", "Check list already contains this task.");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.AddTaskToCheckList(id);
            return PartialView("_LoadCheckList", context.CheckList);
        }
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Also add this string to my View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CheckList)
```

**UPD2:**
My PartialView:

```
@model TaskTracker.Models.CheckList

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Текст задания
        </th>
        <th>
            Дата выполнения
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var task in Model.Tasks)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>task.Value.TaskText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => task.Value.TillDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Not related but what is your `EnumDropDownListFor` for? That will never bind when you submit because your have a `foreach` loop (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943))

Comment: You need to show your partial and the element its being loaded into and how your posting back the data.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'v added UPD. I want to display validation message in main view, not in the pratial.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm using ajax to change state of task when dropdown selection changed.

Comment: Your adding the error to the partial view's `ModelState` - that will not add error to the main view.

Comment: I think you need to change your structure a bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633923/asp-net-mvc-validation-in-partial-view-and-return-to-parent-view

Comment: @StephenMuecke and how I can add error to MainView model state

Comment: You cannot (unless you returned the main view). But there are lots of ways you could handle this (but unless you add the details noted in my 2nd comment, its impossible to tell what is the best way)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'v added my partial view. Model class for this view is check list.

Comment: Since all you displaying is 2 properties, I would forget the obsolete `Ajax` methods and use `$.ajax` and return just a `JsonResult` containing an value indicating success or failure- you already know those 2 values in the view so its just extra overhead to be returning the whole collection of tasks again when you could add the task using javascript/jquery.

Comment: And you can remove/disable the links once you have added the task, minimizing the risk of adding a task that has already been added (I assume multiple users might be adding tasks?). I am about to eat but can add an answer in about 45 min.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's will be greate. But I'm passing whole objects becouse I also want to delete them from check list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147703/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-gleb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display a `ModelState` error from a partial in the main view's `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` - that is razor code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the view, so will display `ModelState` errors from the main views model only.

One option would include moving the `ValidationMessageFor()` to the partial view with the only drawback being the ability to position the element.

However, returning the whole table of added tasks is unnecessary when you already know all the values in the client to append the new row to the table.

Change your code to use the `$.ajax` methods and in the method return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise

Html

```
<a href="#" class="add" data-id="@item.Id">Add To check list</a>
```

Script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("AddToCheckList")';
var table = $('#CheckListPartial table);

$('.add').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var cells = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
    var text = cells.eq(0).text();
    var date = cells.eq(1).text();
    $.post(url, { id: id }, function(result) {
        if (result) {
            // create and append a new row
            var row = $('<tr></tr>');
            row.append($(<td></td>).text(text));
            row.append($(<td></td>).text(date));
            table.append(row);
        } else {
            // display your error
        }
    }).fail(function (result) {
        // display your error
    });
})
```

and the controller method would be

```
public JsonResult AddToCheckList(int id)
{
    if(context.CheckList.Tasks.Exists(t => t.Id == id))
    {
        return Json(null); indicate error - show a hidden element containing a message
    }
    context.AddTaskToCheckList(id);
    return Json(true); // indicate success
}
```

You should also consider removing the link if successful, so the user does not accidentally click it again.

A third alternative would be to generate a checklistbox of all tasks and allow the user to select or unselect items and the post a form and save all taks inone action. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example of the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Tasks to be an `HashSet` and check in the `AddTaskToCheckList` method if it is already there. In that case checking is `O(1)`

```
public void AddTaskToCheckList(int id)
{
    // Find task
    var task = this.Tasks.Find(id);
    if(!this.CheckList.Contains(task))
    {
        this.CheckList.Add(task);
    } 
    else
    {
        // Show error message        
    }   
}
```